# Monitoring Total Network Usage With Python

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to build a network monitoring tool and I'm currently researching how I would go about using raspberry Pis to constantly monitor an entire home networks data usage.

I.e I've currently built a tool that's going to be constantly running on these Pis and I want it to sit on the network and possibly sniff every packet going through the network and calculate it's size and then try and programmatically find out exactly how much data is being used per day or per hour etc.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow may not be the optimal place to ask this kind of question. You may get these answers at LinkedIn's [Python Professionals](https://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=1846027&trk=anet_ug_hm) or [Python Community](https://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=25827&trk=anet_ug_hm).